# Azure Blob Container ResourceNotFound error

Tags: azure, containers, blob

I want to host an installer on our Azure blob storage, so it can be accessed via a url, but the container is inaccessible via the url.

I created the container as follows:-

1) On the Azure Portal, go to Storage Account => Blob service => Containers

2) Click '+ Container', give it a name, and set 'Public access level' to 'Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)'

3) Using CloudBerry Explorer, upload the files to the Container (which shows up and works from there).

Under 'Properties', that container now says it has a URL of 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername', but if I go to that URL I get:-

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:<Guid> Time:2020-01-31T10:12:46.2299517Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

I have also tried:-

1) Setting the 'Access level' to 'Blob (anonymous read access for blobs only)'

2) Adding an 'Access policy', with 'Permissions' set to 'Read' and 'List', and no start or expiry

3) Adding an 'Access policy', with all 'Permissions' set , and a start and expiry time set to before and after the current date respectively.

4) Creating the container and permissions from within CloudBerry (which then still shows up in the Azure Portal, and says it has the correct access level).

Nothing works, every time I try to access the URL I get

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:<Guid> Time:2020-01-31T10:12:46.2299517Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Googling the issue didn't turn up anything I'd not already tried, and most pages simply say set 'Public access level' to 'Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)' which was the first thing I did.

Any kind soul have any ideas?

**Edit**: More Info

It seems the process is partially successful.

The purpose was to host the installer in a blob container, so that Users could download it to install, and from that point on it would auto-update whenever I put a new version up to the container.

The auto-update is working, I just tried it. I installed a version using the local versions of the files that I uploaded to the container originally, then published a new version, uploaded that to the container, and then ran the previously-installed program. It updated itself from the container. So, that part works.

However, I can't see the files on the URL to get the installer in the first place, so Users can't do the initial install.

**Edit #2** : I'm an idiot...

If I specify the filename on the URL (setup.exe), then it downloads and lets me install.

Sorry folks, user error on this one! Was expecting to be able to list the files.

Comment: Are you trying to list the blobs in the container?

Comment: @LMS - great to see, that you kept adding your findings and able to solve.

Comment: I have the same problem, individual files are accessible anonymously but not the container, I was also hoping to see a list. Could you do anything about it?